# DPDT toggle switches vs DPDT slide switches

Tags: switches, schematics

I am wondering if all DPDT switches function the same or if they can differ. I am looking to replace a slide switch with a toggle switch but I am unsure if the circuitry is the same.  In the attached schematic of the slide switch I am looking to replace it seems there are two positions. In position 1, points 1 and 2 are connected as well as points 4 and 5. in position 2 (as shown in schematic), points 2 and 3 are connected as well as 5 and 6. Essentially what I am wondering is if I can purchase any toggle switch specified as DPDT knowing that it has the same functionality as the slide switch I want to replace.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be some exceptions, but typically DPDT toggle switches are pinned out the same way as your diagram. The only difference will be that with a slide switch the actuator will move towards the side whose contacts will be closed while a toggle switch actuator will move the opposite way because it’s a lever. So if you pushed the slide switch up for on and down for off you would push the toggle lever the opposite way, which may be a problem. To solve this you would need to wire it the other way around, which could be a problem if it’s on a circuit board.

If you want to be sure about the pinout the thing to do is look at the datasheet for the switch you are interested in

Comment: Noting that the toggle switch actuator will move opposite the slide switch has definitely saved me a lot of time and effort. Marking as solved.